# Making a program that match two strings if they is identical

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make a program that compares two strings. I want to match `*s1` and `*s2` if they are identical. But, if `s2` contains a star `(’*’)`, we can replace this star by any string (even empty) to make `s1` and `s2` identical, and `s2` can hold as many stars as possible. 
For example, `"main.c"` and `"*.c"` can match because it is possible to replace `’*’` by the string `"main"` to render those two strings identical. What I tried so far can be seen in the code below:

```
     #include

    int identic(char *s1, char *s2)
    { 
       if(*s1 != '\0' && s2 == '')
           return (identic(s1 + 1, s2) || identic(s1, s2 + 1)); 
       if(*s1 == '\0' && s2 == '') 
           return (identic(s1, s2 + 1));
       if(*s1 == *s2 && *s2 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
           return (identic(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));
       if(*s1 == *s2 && *s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0') 
           return (1); 
       return (0);     
    } 
    int main() { 
        printf("%c\n", identic("asfd", "f"));
    }
```

Comment: Victor: The code is in `C` not `C++`.

Comment: Writing that program is a lot harder than it sounds (especially if you allow multiple `*` characters.

Comment: Did you not get a compiler error? "error: empty character constant"
`if(*s1 != '\0' && s2 == '')`

Comment: Lennart suggests how to fix your program to compile and run, but even then, the algorithm you've implemented runs in exponential time in the worst case. `identic("********************a", "********************b")` is a good test case. https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html describes a linear-time algorithm for general regexp matching, from which you could figure out how to specialize to glob matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replace `s2 == ''` with `*s2 == '*'` and `#include` with `#include <stdio.h>`, your code seems to work fine.